# Can someone identify all the characters in this Marvel Not Brand Echh panel?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

Marvel's *Not Brand Echh* was a satirical magazine poking fun at the "Distinguished Competition", published in the 1960s. Since I wasn't around then, some of the jokes and references require a quick Google (for example AuH2O referring to Senator Barry Goldwater.)

In this panel there are many characters, some Marvel related mixed with (what I assume are) public figures and celebrities of the time. While I recognise some of them, it would be helpful if someone could identify the other ones

[image: Not Brand Echh panel]

Comment: i see Thor, Nixon, the Beatles, MLK, Muhammad Ali, and I think that's Colin Baker on the left?

Comment: Alfred E. Neumann on the right. Martin Luthor King Jr. on the left.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield Hey hey, it’s the Monkees!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So far, I have identified (top-to-bottom, left-to-right):

[image]

1. [King Konk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2H5zm.jpg), parody of [King Kong](http://www.fact.co.uk/media/2804178/King%20Kong%201.jpg)
2. [Kid Cold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdDT9m.jpg), parody of [Kid Colt](http://i.newsarama.com/images/i/000/003/688/i02/Kid_Colt-ff.jpg?1363790246)
3. (generic knight -- no ID)
4. (generic outline -- no ID)
5. [Baron von Strucker](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/1/19/Wolfgang_von_Strucker_(Earth-7918).jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090828032306)
6. (generic outline -- no ID)
7. [Jackie Gleason](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Jackie_Gleason_-_1966.jpg)
8. [Dr. Bloom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUOGcm.jpg), parody of [Dr. Doom](http://media.eventhubs.com/images/mvc3/character_header_doctor_doom.jpg)
9. [J. Jawbone Junkton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEgU9m.gif), parody of [J. Jonah Jameson](http://www.thedarktower.org/gallery/data/623/JJJameson1.jpg), with a [*Conan*](http://www.vaultcollectibles.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/s-l1600-3.jpg)-style arm rising beside him.
10. [Charles de Gaulle](http://www.historylearningsite.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/charle3.jpg)
11. [Grandpa Munster](https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/granpamunster__120320184226.png), from the Munsters
12. [Herman Munster](http://www.munsters.com/images/herman-cast.jpg), from the Munsters
13. [Peter Sellers](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Sellers-1966.jpg)
14. [Elizabeth Taylor](http://static01.nyt.com/images/2011/03/24/obituaries/24taylor/24taylor-popup.jpg)
15. [Richard Burton](https://interlitq.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/richard_burton.jpg)
16. [Alfred E. Neuman](http://media.dcentertainment.com/sites/default/files/MAD-Magazine-Alfred-E-Neuman-Norman-Mingo.jpg), mascot for from Mad Magazine
17. [Bob Dylan](http://schoolofgroove.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Micro-Bob.jpg), drawn badly enough to also look like [Art Garfunkel](https://cdn-s3.allmusic.com/release-covers/250/0001/333/0001333457.jpg)
18. [Muhammed Ali](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/424184673938329600/FArA372x_400x400.jpeg)
19. [Mitch Miller](http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/3/JPG_400/MI0001/423/MI0001423440.jpg)
20. [Frank Sinatra](http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTYzMzM2ODgzM15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwOTc5MzM2._V1_SX640_SY720_.jpg)
21. [Mia Farrow](http://theredlist.com/media/database/muses/icon/cinematic_women/1970/mia-farrow/027-mia-farrow-theredlist.jpg)
22. [Bobby Kennedy](http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large/sen-robert-kennedy-talking-everett.jpg)
23. [Martin Luther King Jr.](http://a4.files.biography.com/image/upload/c_fit,cs_srgb,dpr_1.0,h_1200,q_80,w_1200/MTE5NTU2MzE2MjgwNDg5NDgz.jpg)
24. [Mao Zedong](http://a1.files.biography.com/image/upload/c_fit,cs_srgb,dpr_1.0,h_1200,q_80,w_1200/MTE5NDg0MDU1MDYwMjUyMTc1.jpg)
25. [Lyndon B. Johnson](http://www.bradwarthen.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/lbj-cowboy-hat.jpg)
26. [Auntie Mayhem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9KHym.jpg), parody of Spiderman's [Aunt May](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/3/39001/874441-460443321_ed75321b56_o.jpg)
27. (generic orc)
28. [Davy Jones](http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/30900000/Davy-Jones-davy-jones-monkees-30986438-705-480.jpg), of The Monkees
29. [Mickey Dolenz](http://photos.famouswiki.com/m/micky-dolenz-20961/gallery/micky-dole-280160.jpg), of The Monkees
30. [Michael Nesmith](http://storage.torontosun.com/v1/blogs-prod-photos/1/9/1/1/4/191146595df81e1a111832cf4b1e18fd.jpg?), of The Monkees
31. [Peter Tork](http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/33100000/Peter-Tork-peter-tork-33135079-754-1052.jpg), of The Monkees
32. [Don Knotts](http://amayberrystateofmind.com/attachments/Image/Don-Knotts-don-knotts-22502121-280-350.jpg)
33. [The Mighty Sore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP9hmm.jpg), parody of Marvel's [Thor](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_medium/5/54353/2019392-thor___1st_app_kirby_02_color.jpg)

edit: Incorporated the *Not Brand Echh* identities from the answers below.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YF3gd.jpg

Comment: Colin Baker wouldn't fit; his earliest IMDB credit is in 1970, his reign as The Doctor is 1983-86.

Comment: Harpo Marx, maybe?

Comment: @Politank-Z yeah but no other Doctor Who looks like him and he's under a sign that says "Take an immortal to lunch" The 60's Doctors would be Hartnell or Troughton :\

Comment: 17 would be Bob Dylan (note the harmonica holder and the wild curly hair), 26 is Aunt May. I suspect that the arm with the sword is actually separate from 9/J Jonah Jameson. Prince Valiant or Conan maybe?

Comment: the harmonica holder is persuasive; but Dylan's hair was never blond and not really *that* curly; plus I can't see him in a yellow suit...

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - A picture from 66-68 wouldn't reference a performance from 1983.  It's Dylan.  Also, the old lady might be Granny from the Beverly Hillbillies or Ruth Buzzi as the old lady on Laugh In.

Comment: Yellowish brown jacket = http://images.popmatters.com/news_art/b/bob-dylan-the-freewheelin-bob-dylan.jpg

Comment: #17 - Looks more like Art Garfunkel with that hair, although the harmonica does suggest Bob Dylan.

Comment: Oh you spotted it.

Comment: http://kirbymuseum.org/blogs/dynamics/2012/06/21/not-brand-echh-identifications/

Comment: @Wad Cheber Actually, after rereading the issue he appeared in, I got my western heroes mixed up: #2 is Kid Cold / Kid Colt. Two-Gun Kid wears a similar vest, but has a black hat and mask.

Answer (score 9):

The ones I recognized:

- Alfred E. Neuman

[image]
[image]

- Thor

[image]

- Herman Munster

[image]

- Grandpa Munster

[image]

- Martin Luther King Jr.

[image] [image]

- Dr. Doom

[image]

- Mao Tse-Tung

[image]

- Muhammad Ali

[image]

- The Monkees

[image]

- John Wayne (?)

[image]

- Bob Dylan

[image]

- Don Knotts

[image]

- Charles de Gaulle

[image]

- Robert F. Kennedy

[image]

- Jackie Gleason

[image]

- Mitch Miller

[image]

- Lyndon B. Johnson

[image]

- Richard Burton and Elizabeth Taylor

[image]

- Frank sinatra and his wife, Mia Farrow

[image]

- King Kong

[image]

Comment: Not Paul McCartney.  The band in the lower left is the Monkees.  The one you think is Paul is actually Davy Jones.

Comment: Which one's Mickey Dolenz?

Comment: @MikeEdenfield  - the top

Comment: Not Frankenstein's monster - Herman and Grandpa from The Munsters.

Comment: really... Frankenstein's Monster vs. Hermen Munster is a toss-up

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - It looks like Fred Gwynne.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield In isolation, I would tend to agree with you, but when paired with the rather iconic Grandpa Munster, not so much.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Mike Edenfields answer, the Marvel characters in the picture are actually the Not Brand Ecch-verse parody versions of those characters. To elaborate:

2: Kid Cold (parody of Kid Colt)

8: Dr. Bloom

9: J. Jawbone Junkton

26: Aunt May. No parody name for her.

33: The Mighty Sore (Yes, that is a pigeon on his helmet.)

Comment: Number 1, King Kong, was also parodied by Not Brand Echh in issue 11, with name King Konk.

Comment: @Jack Graveney True, but the image is from Not Brand Ecch #3, published over a year earlier. Also, King Konk has a way larger forehead and never eats a lollipop in his story (see here: http://imgur.com/iPiSFPq) - pretty sure that is just a generic gorilla.

Answer (score 5):

The website [Kirby Museum](http://kirbymuseum.org/blogs/dynamics/2012/06/21/not-brand-echh-identifications/) offers this identification of the real people in the picture:

[image]

The others, with the exception of the one I believe to be Peter Sellers (marked with a "?"), are Not Brand Echh characters.

The Mighty Sore
[image]

J. Jawbone Junkton
[image]

Dr. Bloom
[image]
[image]

[Auntie Mayhem](http://www.comicvine.com/auntie-mayhem/4005-93538/)
[image]
[image]

[Kid Cold/Too Gone Kid](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Not_Brand_Echh_Vol_1_1#Appearing_in_.22The_Fastest_Gums_in_the_West.21.22) (parody of Kid Colt/Two Gun Kid)
[image]
[image]

King Konk?
[image]

As Wikipedia says, gorillas were a marketing gimmick in Silver Age Comics, so the gorilla could be [any number of characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorillas_in_comics).